# Not able to start a Spring Cloud Config Server from start.spring.io

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I'm trying to build a Spring Cloud Config Server using JDBC to store the configurations. However I can't seem to run the Application. I haven't yet added the @EnableConfigServer, I was just trying to run it straight from start.spring.io

The error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor
(Full stacktrace bellow - Stacktrace 1)

The pom:

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

...

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If I add:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I get the error: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.KeyProperties
(Full stacktrace bellow - Stacktrace 2)

Stacktrace 1:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor]
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:334) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:446) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:369) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:285) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:102) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:81) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitionForImportedConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:160) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at pt.nm.services.configserver.NmServicesConfigServerApplication.main(NmServicesConfigServerApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:324) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
... 25 common frames omitted
```

Stacktrace 2:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.KeyProperties]
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:334) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:446) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:369) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:285) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:102) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:81) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitionForImportedConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:160) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at pt.nm.services.configserver.NmServicesConfigServerApplication.main(NmServicesConfigServerApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.KeyProperties
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:324) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
... 25 common frames omitted
```

Comment: can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: @spencergibb Added both stack traces. With and without the spring-boot-starter-security

Comment: are you missing any spring cloud dependencies from you pom? You don't show any. Have you tried forcing a refresh of the dependencies `mvn -U` seems like you might have corrupt downloads.